Image Texture only work on Texture Paint
I was trying to make a model for the game VRChat, but when I try to export it to Blender I saw that the material didn't work and when I check it in Blender it's looks like the UV was right and in Texture Paint it looks good but in the material preview it doesn't work.
The weird thing it's that when I use a brick texture or a wave it works.
Material Preview

Material Preview

Texture Paint

Unity (The plane share the same material as the avatar)


hello could you please pack your images and share your file?

I try to pack it but i saw an error so i upload the blend file with the texture to file transfer, i hope it work link

look into the Data panel > UV Maps, you have 2 UV maps, it's the first one that is used by default when you'll render, if it's not what you want, plug an Input > UV Map node into your Image Texture and choose the second one (or simply remove the first UV map):

